# ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=519x600 at 0x7F95AD916518>) with an unsupported type

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-requests, python-imaging-library

while i was opening and decoding an image from python with tensorflow  i got an error

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
response = requests.get(r'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Felis_silvestris_silvestris_small_gradual_decrease_of_quality.png')
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

tf_image = tf.io.read_file(img)
```

error is hapenning when i used `tf.io.read_file(img)` 
Throws error of

> > ---
> >
> > _FallbackException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
> >     /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py
> >     in read_file(filename, name)
> >         548         _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "ReadFile", name,
> >     --> 549         tld.op_callbacks, filename)
> >         550       return _result
>
> _FallbackException: This function does not handle the case of the path where all inputs are not already EagerTensors.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last) 7 frames
>   /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/framework/constant_op.py
>   in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
>        94       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
>        95   ctx.ensure_initialized()
>   ---> 96   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
>        97 
>        98
>
> ValueError: Attempt to convert a value
>   () with an unsupported type () to a Tensor.

Comment: You have already converted the PNG file into an *"in-memory"* representation of an image with `Image.open()` so you don't want to read another file in `tf`. If `tf` is looking for a Numpy array, use `tf_image = np.array(img)`