# getting image from url and want to predict image from own classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

i trained a model that will classfied image everything is working fine when i put send image directly from frontend but now i want to get image from url and predict that.
consider i have a url like :  `www.example.com/image.jpg`
my code is:

```
 url = 'https://icon2.cleanpng.com/20171220/gze/twitter-logo-png-5a3a1851372e76.0876249315137567532269680.jpg'
 response = requests.get(url)
 img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
 imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
 img_test = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
 classes = np.argmax(parrotModel.predict(img_test), axis=-1)
 print(str(classes[0]))
```

error :

````
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=626x417 at 0x7FD401D29898>) with an unsupported type (<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>) to a Tensor.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to convert the image to a `numpy` array.

```
img_test = tf.expand_dims(np.array(img), axis=0)
```

Also, have a look here: [ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=519x600 at 0x7F95AD916518>) with an unsupported type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044385/valueerror-attempt-to-convert-a-value-pil-pngimageplugin-pngimagefile-image-m) , a similar problem was discussed.